# Website redirect is not working without www subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, deployment, dns, aws-amplify

I am deploying my website with AWS Amplify with custom domain in GoDaddy. My DNS records and nameservers are managed in GoDaddy. Website is hosted with AWS Amplify. I already set up redirect in AWS Amplify.
[AWS Amplify Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5seWm.png)
But my website wont redirect when I enter https://example.com in the browser.

1. example.com is working fine.
2. https://www.example.com is working fine.
3. https://example.com is Not working!

Please help me out, I am quite inexperienced in deployments.  I tried to play around the GoDaddy DNS records but it does not work.